# Using PDOStatement::prepare with PostGIS functions

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, postgis

I am fairly new to PDO, so excuse me if I misunderstood some things. I spent quite some time reading through the materials available online but couldnt find a proper solution.

The code I am trying to program is supposed to do the following: Take two $_GET variables containing a certain points latitude ($lat) and longitude ($lon) and then SELECT the closest point to these coordinates stored in a PostGIS-enabled database (plus return distance to that point). This is what the current (and working) code piece looks like:

```
$courts = $pdo->query("SELECT * , ST_ASTEXT(geog) , ST_distance( ST_GeographyFromText('POINT($lon $lat)') , geog ) AS distance FROM bvbcourts WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeographyFromText('POINT($lon $lat)' ) , geog , 20000) ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1");
```

However, I wanted to try using prepare statements, since I read that these are SQL injection proof.

```
$courts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * , ST_ASTEXT(geog) , ST_distance( ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( :lon :lat )') , geog ) AS distance FROM bvbcourts WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( :lon :lat )' ) , geog , 20000) ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1" );
$courts->execute(array( ':lon' => $lon , ':lat' => $lat ) )
```

But code above doesnt work. Executing errorInfo() only returned the following error code: `HY093`

From what I've learned so far I assume the code above doesn't work, because `->prepare` placeholders can only be used where you would normaly insert an input parameter.

E.g. `->prepare( "SELECT * FROM x WHERE field=:field" );` would work
whereas `->prepare( "SELECT * FROM x WHERE field='someprefix:field'" );` wouldnt. And the code I am trying to use above is somewhat similar to the "someprefix"-example.

So, my question is, how do I get the statement I am trying to execute to work without having to use `->query` and manually preventing injections. Or would I be better off just making sure that the parameters passed are proper, plain coordinates and use `->query`?

This is only my second question asked here so excuse me if I wasn't being clear or thorough enough with my research and information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to *not* create a WKT string, but to pass the coordinate floats directly to a PostGIS geometry constructor. Here is what your prepare statement should look like.

```
SELECT *, ST_ASTEXT(geog), ST_Distance(poi, geog) AS distance
FROM bvbcourts,
 (SELECT ST_MakePoint(:lon, :lat)::geography AS poi) AS f
WHERE ST_DWithin(poi, geog, 20000)
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The ST_MakePoint solution works as well and is, according to the PostGIS documentation, a little faster than ST_GeographyFromText (see here [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/which-function-for-creating-a-point-in-postgis)). For me it's also quite a bit easier to use since I can use the same coding style as in other queries and don't have to add a check whether the input parameters are acutally floats. However, the documentation also states that ST_MakePoint is not OGC compliant. Could this be a problem in the future (e.g. when migrating to a different dbms)?

Comment: Correct, `ST_MakePoint` is not OGC compliant, thus not available on different DBMS, but the geography type (and `ST_GeographyFromText`) are not part of OGC either. I know MS SQL Server has a similar type, but not sure about the others.

Answer (score 2):

I really wish to know how to make basic knowledge on the topic available to newcomers.

To a constant beholder these questions seems quite repetitive. that makes a programmer think of inefficiency of the site. Yet it seems site policy encourage duplicating questions. So, here it goes.

A prepared statement can represent **compete data literal** only. Frankly - a complete **string** or **number**

Look an your code:

```
'POINT($lon $lat)'
```

is a data literal already. So, you cannot make a literal to be a part of a literal. You have to bind it whole:

```
$courts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * , ST_ASTEXT(geog) , ST_distance( ST_GeographyFromText(:point) , geog ) AS distance FROM bvbcourts WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeographyFromText(:point ) , geog , 20000) ORDER BY distance LIMIT 1" );
$courts->execute(array( ':point' => "POINT($lon $lat)") );
```